# Encoding of special chars in SOAP (Java JAX-WS)

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, special-characters, marshalling

I'm using the Java JAX-WS framework to communicate via SOAP.
I'm using the "code-first" approach and have a simple interface with a single function

```
    @WebMethod String sendString(String string);
```

The sent string might contain special character like `>` which are then correctly encoded in the sent XML by `&gt;`.

However, when I send a carriage return `\r` in Java 8, it is no longer encoded as `&#xD;` as it used to be in Java 7, but is instead transformed into a newline `\n`. This of course causes the received string to be different than the sent string which is a problem in my application.

Is there a way to configure that behavior? Any other helpful ideas and insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, the behavior seems to be OS-dependent :-O

Comment: Similar questions on SO are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056815/jaxb-seems-to-be-re-encoding-new-line-char and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077853/jax-ws-webmethod-response-encode-special-characters